# Html Div Using Social Media buttons

Tags: html, css

trying to make social media top bar. i can make facebook, twitter, linkedin but when i made phone and mail , its just like the picture and mixing.

How can i widen these? Please help me.

Codes are below

Thank you.

```
<div class="col-xs-2 col-sm-6">

                        <!-- header-top-first start -->
                        <!-- ================ -->
                        <div class="header-top-first clearfix">
                            <ul class="social-links clearfix hidden-xs">
                                <li class="twitter"><a target="_blank" href="https://twitter.com/abc"><i class="fa fa-twitter"></i></a></li>
                                <!-- <li class="skype"><a target="_blank" href="http://www.skype.com"><i class="fa fa-skype"></i></a></li> -->
                                <li class="linkedin"><a target="_blank" href="https://www.linkedin.com/company/abc"><i class="fa fa-linkedin"></i></a></li>
                                <!-- <li class="googleplus"><a target="_blank" href="http://plus.google.com"><i class="fa fa-google-plus"></i></a></li>
                                <li class="youtube"><a target="_blank" href="http://www.youtube.com"><i class="fa fa-youtube-play"></i></a></li>
                                <li class="flickr"><a target="_blank" href="http://www.flickr.com"><i class="fa fa-flickr"></i></a></li> -->
                                <li class="facebook"><a target="_blank" href="https://www.facebook.com/abc/"><i class="fa fa-facebook"></i></a></li>
                                <!-- <li class="pinterest"><a target="_blank" href="http://www.pinterest.com"><i class="fa fa-pinterest"></i></a></li> -->
                                <li class="instagram"><a target="_blank" href="https://www.instagram.com/abc/"><i class="fa fa-instagram"></i></a></li>
                                <li class="phone" ><a target="_blank" href="http://www.companyname.com" ><i class="fa fa-phone">5555 55 55</i></a></li>
                                <li class="mail"><a target="_blank" href="mailto:info@abc.com"><i class="fa fa-envelope last">info@abc.com</i></a></li>

                            </ul>

                            <div class="social-links hidden-lg hidden-md hidden-sm">
                                <div class="btn-group dropdown">
                                    <button type="button" class="btn dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown"><i class="fa fa-share-alt"></i></button>
                                    <ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-animation">
                                        <li class="twitter"><a target="_blank" href="https://twitter.com/abc"><i class="fa fa-twitter"></i></a></li>
                                        <!-- <li class="skype"><a target="_blank" href="http://www.skype.com"><i class="fa fa-skype"></i></a></li> -->
                                        <li class="linkedin"><a target="_blank" href="https://www.linkedin.com/company/abc"><i class="fa fa-linkedin"></i></a></li>
                                        <!-- <li class="googleplus"><a target="_blank" href="http://plus.google.com"><i class="fa fa-google-plus"></i></a></li>
                                        <li class="youtube"><a target="_blank" href="http://www.youtube.com"><i class="fa fa-youtube-play"></i></a></li>
                                        <li class="flickr"><a target="_blank" href="http://www.flickr.com"><i class="fa fa-flickr"></i></a></li> -->
                                        <li class="facebook"><a target="_blank" href="https://www.facebook.com/abc/"><i class="fa fa-facebook"></i></a></li>
                                        <!-- <li class="pinterest"><a target="_blank" href="http://www.pinterest.com"><i class="fa fa-pinterest"></i></a></li> -->
                                        <li class="instagram"><a target="_blank" href="https://www.instagram.com/abc/"><i class="fa fa-instagram"></i></a></li>
                                        <li class="phone"><a target="_blank" href="http://www.companyname.com" ><i class="fa fa-phone">5555 55 55</i></a></li>
                                        <li class="mail"><a target="_blank" href="mailto:info@abc.com"><i class="fa fa-envelope last">info@abc.com</i></a></li>

                                    </ul>

                                </div>
                            </div>

                        </div>
                        <!-- header-top-first end -->

                    </div>
```

[image: Error]

[image: picture with no text]

Comment: may be the parent div 'col-sm-6' won't be enough space increase its size by giving 'col-sm-7' or 'col-sm-8'

Comment: thanks for repling tried and still same

Comment: What happens if you remove: "5555 55 55" and "info@abc.com" - Looks like the content is too big for your li element, is your li element a specific width?

Comment: it smaller , yeah i think so the problem is all items has the same width but i tried it on <li> with width and it has not changed again

Comment: the new picture like that when i remove 5555 55 55 and info@abc.com

Comment: Can you also share your CSS? or even better, reformat your question with snippet instead of just an image.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to put inside the parent class "justify-content-around" or "justify-content-between"?

Comment: how can i do it?

Comment: in every <divElement>, you have class="somethingCool" beside <div> and </div>. Inside this, add " justify-content-around". It would have the same effect as flexbox system. Actually, your project use Boostrap class who is running as flexbox.

Comment: thank you tried it but did not work, the problem is all elements are the same width and i tried to change it on <li> tag with width but it has not changed again

Comment: try to add w-auto to your class. your elements will take the necessary space normaly. maybe you will need to configure this space

Comment: yeah you were right, i found it on css style document and solved it thank you